# How to peek into a Linux (POSIX) message queue without removing an item?

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I need to peek into a message queue without removing them. I will go ahead and remove the message queue item only if it complies to certain criteria. How to do this? Following are the APIs I know — but none seems support peeking.

- `mq_close()` — close a message queue
- `mq_getattr()` — get the current attributes of a message queue
- `mq_notify()` — notify the calling process when the queue becomes nonempty
- `mq_open()` — open or create a message queue
- `mq_receive()` — receive a message from a queue
- `mq_send()` — put a message into a message queue
- `mq_setattr()` — set the flags for a message queue
- `mq_unlink()` — unlink (i.e. delete) a message queue

Is there a way to peek at a message without removing it?

Comment: this doens't mesh well with transactional requirements. I expect the best you could do is use separate queues or put the message back onto the queue after inspecting.

Comment: 2 things you can try: - "mount -t mqeue /dev/mqueue ..." (mentioned in the mq_overview man page) and then try to sneak into the messages - or use the libko (non standard): http://julien.benoist.name/libko.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peeking is probably a bad idea for a message queue because, like sehe noted, the danger of race conditions. Just assume you have peeked a message; since you cannot lock the queue, you will be unable to reliably retrieve the same message you have peeked. If you have two processes receiving mutually exclusive messages from the same queue, you should be thinking about separating these messages into two queues, for clarity of design and race condition stability.

Answer made short: A peek is very unlikely because it would need explicit locking semantics to carry it out stably.