# Does Macintosh have a message based paradigm like Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, unix, system

I'm new to Systems programming and I thought you might be able to help.

I'm learning Message based programming (like getmessage()) on Windows, and many of my sources refer to this as a characteristic windows thing.

Is this a paradigm on Mac? Is there an equivalent of getmessage() or peekmessage() on Unix based operating systems? or are events handled differently?

If they are significantly different I would love to hear the pro's and con's.

Comment: While never having done any programming on OSX, I would think that programming involving the GUI would be event based, similar to the Windows system, but that the abstractions would be different. In the bottom there probably is a message queue of some kind, but it might be more hidden. I suggest you read tutorials on programming on OSX first, and if you have a specific problem you can come back and ask about that.

Comment: As far as I know, Objective-C/Cocoa based programming is all about being object based and passing messages between those objects. I have no idea how that compares to Windows' `getmessage`, but message passing is a fundamental part of Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [message queue](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview), which is covered in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401642/how-to-peek-into-a-linux-posix-message-queue-without-removing-an-item) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401642/how-to-peek-into-a-linux-posix-message-queue-without-removing-an-item) unrelated questions, and ironically an [inverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989702/is-there-was-a-mechanism-in-windows-works-like-message-queue-in-linux). It is available for most Unix-based operating systems, but not [BSD derivatives like OSX](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/mq_005fsend.html), which has its own Cocoa based [NSOperationQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsoperationqueue) as well as support for [Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch). Here are a few commands:

- `mq_send`
- `mq_receive`

**References**

- [libdispatch](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly not an expert in programming for Apples IOS, but I have done enough to know the basics of it. What I know is that it's all event based like Windows .NET Forms and WPF. I didn't see any code using Cocoa that had anything equivalent to a message loop. Also in the books I read, I didn't see or read anything that would steer readers towards any API like that. If you are going to program in IOS, I strongly suggest just sticking to the accepted norms of IOS. That means don't force one programming concept on a system that was not designed to accept it.